# Save text from an HTML page to a variable to use as an input for a separate jQuery function

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm trying to save the VIN under Specifications to a variable so I can use it for a separate jQuery function.
https://www.edmundsonrv.com/New-Inventory-2021-Cruiser-RV-Trailer-Shadow-Cruiser-239RBS-Cruiser-RV-Shadow-Cruiser-Edmundson-RV-Sales-Service-9739013?ref=list

Answer (score 0):

$('.LiInvvin .unitValue').text()